# Show if 30 minutes before current time

Tags: php, date, time, conditional-statements

I need a registration button to disappear 30 minutes before a meeting starts. My meeting date is stored in one field and the start time is in another field. The conditional code for the date is working fine but, not in combination with the time code. I have the following code but, it isn't working correctly.

```
<?php
    if ($meetings->getColumnVal("meeting_date") >= date('Y-m-d')) {
        if (date("h:i") > date("h:i", strtotime('-30 minutes', $meetings->getColumnVal("start_time")))) { ?>
            <br><a href="register.php?meetingID=<?php echo($meetings->getColumnVal("theID")); ?>" title="register">Register to Attend</a>
        <?php }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Please format and indent the code block in a readable fashion.

Comment: Doing date maths with texts doesn't make much sense. In lexicographical order, `09:00 pm` comes before `10:00 am`.

Comment: I tried to reformat it. Does this look better. The times are stored in my database in this format: 20:30.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(time() <= strtotime("-30 minutes", strtotime( $meetings->getColumnVal("meeting_date")." ".$meetings->getColumnVal("start_time")  ))){
// time is less than 30 minutes ago from meeting start_time
}
```

1. Concat `$meetings->getColumnVal("meeting_date")` and `$meetings->getColumnVal("start_time")`
2. Generate Unix time for the concatenated date string with `strtotime()`
3. Subtract 30 minutes from the unix time with integer subtraction of `-1800` or, `strtotime("-30 minutes", $unix_time)`
4. Compare new unix time with current time `time()`

One more thing you have to check is that your PHP timezone and MySQL timezone are the same.